Determination of null point in a field with more than two charges
To determine the null point of two like charges is to find the point where the net electric force is zero.
However, when it comes to three charges with two like charges and one unlike charge, or five charges with one least one pair of like charges (as in the diagram below), I am easily addled by the sheer number of forces I have to consider, hence my failure to determine the null point.
May I know if there is a more systematic way to approach any cases necessitating the determination of null points?


With the given symmetries, can you identify special locations that could contain a zero electric field vector (possibly by ruling out places the field vector can’t be zero)? Give specific examples of what have you tried.

It might be helpful to study your configuration using https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/charges-and-fields/latest/charges-and-fields_all.html (turn on the grid to help with placement). Use "sensor" to probe the electric field.
